# How to set path tracing tile

Tags: rendering

I want to set path tracing tile from 240 to 150 or any which i want. I want to know how can i make changes in the settings to lower the path tracing tile.

[image]

Default Sample setting

[image]

What changes i can make so that i can lower or increase the path tracing tile from 240. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: You cant just control the number of tiles directly, only their size, which will then be computed to cover the whole image, resulting in X number of tiles.

Answer (score -1):

Its under the **[performance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/performance.html)** section under render settings, but not with tile count, but tilesize.

Comment: Sorry did not get what u mean

Comment: You were right the just had to scroll down further and there should be the section Performance under that there should be tiles X and Y (Properties>Render>Performance>Tiles)

Comment: below its default x64 and y64 if multiply 4096 and when render it show 240.

Comment: @atek If you render to  a 640 x 640 image (10 x 10) tiles, with render scale at 50% it shows 25 as expected.  What is the 4096?

Comment: @CedricvandenBerg Please add a screenshot of the area in question and edit your answer. The answer is correct, but in its current form only understandable for someone who anyways knows where to look for that property.